# What is the excel formula for "if a cell is one of N top values of the column"?

Tags: excel

Column A has 50 random values (from A1 to A50). I'm trying to make formula for each cell of column B. The formula is: if the value of left cell is one of top 3 values of column A, then write "Yes", else write "No". I tried to use this in cell B1:

```
=IF(A1=LARGE(A1:A50,{1;2;3}),"Yes","No")
```

But it doesn't work perfectly because it only works on the largest value, not the second and third values.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the desired output if two values are tied for 3rd place?

Comment: @ExactaBox: the desired output is "Yes" for the upper cell, and "No" for the lower Cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first and second-largest values are larger than (or equal to) the 3rd largest, so:

```
=IF(A1>=LARGE($A$1:$A$50,3),"yes","no")
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mr ExactaBox

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

=IF(A1>LARGE(A1:A50,4),"Yes","No")

You might also consider:

=IF(RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$50)<=3,"yes","no")

Comment: you might run into trouble if there is a tie for 3rd ... this formula would return "no" for the tied values in that case.  OP doesn't specifically state what the desired result is in that case so it might not be incorrect.

Comment: Genius... Thanks so much Mr Rory

Comment: @ExactaBox: what do tied values mean?

Comment: @Ray tied values = equal.  What if the top 5 values are 748, 736, 725, 725, 719 ?

Comment: @ExactaBox: Okay, I see. Thanks again Mr ExactaBox

Comment: Say you had 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5 as values - because of the repeating 3 value, LARGE(..., 3) and LARGE(..., 4) both return 3, so my formula would say "no" for 3. Of course the same problem can occur if higher values repeat using >=LARGE(...3), depending on your definition of top 3.